# How to convert string to array yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have a Product model and Product controller:

```
public function actionGet($id) {
    Yii::$app->response->format = Yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ['product' => Product::findOne($id)];
}
```

In my DB, I got `products.images` column, there's an array with images:

```
["product.png", "product2.jpg"]
```

When I do an request to `/products/get?id=1`, I have a response with the string `images`, but I need an array with images. How to convert `images` to array in Product model? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save this `["product.png", "product2.jpg"]` as an array in the DB. This is just text.

You can however save a json string rep of your array. ie:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if(isset($this->images) && is_array($this->images))
      $this->images = \yii\helpers\Json::encode($this->images);
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Then you can decode this using afterFind:

```
public function afterFind()
{
    if(isset($this->images)
        $this->images = \yii\helpers\Json::decode($this->images);
    return parent::afterFind();
}
```

Comment: `afterSave()` method requires $changedAttribute array. What should I pass here?

Comment: @Alexxosipov It will be `beforeSave()` not `afterSave()`. Change to `parent::beforeSave()`